# java insert in Map<String, Set<String>>

Tags: java, hashmap, set

In C++ I can do:

```
map<string, set<string>> v; 
v["AHA"].insert("BA");
```

In java I have:

```
 HashMap<String, Set<String>> v = new HashMap<String, Set<String>>();
```

How I can insert "BA" to v["AHA"] as some as c++?

Yes I try this:

```
Set<String> vs = V.get("B");
if (vs == null) vs = new HashSet<String>();
vs.add("V");
V.put("B", vs);
```

but is large

Comment: `v.get("AHA").add("BA")`  See [`Map.get()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#get-java.lang.Object-) and [`Set.add()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#add-java.lang.Object-)

Comment: @khelwood, but if v.get("AHA") is null it is not work, I should do only check always if (v.get("AHA") != null) ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to add something into the set, and allow for the possibility that the key/value pair might not yet exist in the map, you can use [`computeIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-)

```
v.computeIfAbsent("AHA", k -> new HashSet<String>()).add("BA")
```

This will look up the key in the map, and if it is missing, add it with a new empty set as the value, so you can then add stuff straight into it.

If you're using a version of Java before Java 8, it's a little more code:

```
Set<String> s = v.get("AHA");
if (s==null) {
    s = new HashSet<String>();
    v.put("AHA", s);
}
s.add("BA");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
HashMap<String, Set<String>> v = new HashMap<String, Set<String>>();
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
set.add("some data");
v.put("AHA",set);
```

Create a Set first and then store it in Map.

Comment: I can insert in add in set, that already exists. In c++ I can insert v["AHA"].insert("BA"); v["AHA"].insert("BF"); etc. some times. In java I can't do it without checking on NULL ?